# CSV parsing in iOS by line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, csv

I'm parsing a CSV file in objective-c. The file contains something like this:

```
line 40 | Rising searches
line 41 | nabi avcÄ±,Breakout
line 42 | stonewall,+700%
line 43 | medgar evers,+500%
line 44 | lgbt,+350%
line 45 | roe v wade,+350%
line 46 | Î±ÏÎµÏÎ³Î¹Î±,+250%
```

I want to get the contents of lines 41 to 50 (inclusive). I then want to separate the each line into two `NSStrings` one containing the stuff before the `,` and the other with the stuff after it. How can I do that?

Any help is really strongly appreciated. Thx! Antoine

Comment: I'd use JSON. More human readable, easy to parse, take whatever data you need, whatever range...

Comment: @SavaMazăre, the OP may not be generating the data to be parsed. There's still a lot of data out there in CSV format, particularly because it's so easy to export from Excel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try playing around with Dave DeLong's CHCSVParser. https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

You can initialize the parser with the path to you CSV file (assuming you have a CHCSVParser *_parser instance variable):

```
NSString *filePath = ...; // the path to your CSV file
_parser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVFile:filePath];
_parser.delegate = self;
[_parser parse];
```

Then you should use a combination of three delegate methods to customize the parser and make it fit your needs:

```
- (void)parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didBeginLine:(NSUInteger)recordNumber
{
    // Only parse the fields on lines 41 to 50
    // _shouldParseLine is an ivar that is set to YES
    // only when the fields inside the following line or lines
    // should be parsed.
    if (recordNumber == 41) {
        _shouldParseLine = YES;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didEndLine:(NSUInteger)recordNumber 
{
    if (recordNumber == 50) {
        // The parser has finished parsing the 50th line
        // We're done, cancel any further parsing.
        // It is not necessary to set _shouldParseLine to NO, 
        // since the parser is killed here and the didReadField
        // delegate method will not be called again.
        [parser cancelParsing];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(CHCSVParser *)parser didReadField:(NSString *)field atIndex:(NSInteger)fieldIndex
{
    if (_shouldParseLine == YES) {
        // Here are your fields.
        // The field at index 0 consists of the text
        // before the comma, the field at index 1
        // consists of the text after the comma.
    }
}
```