# Reading/Writing xls/csv files in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to parse any xls/csv file using objective C.
Can anyone suggest any library that can be used and a sample on how to use it.
Thanks.

Comment: Please can you show some code and workings for what you have already tried?

Comment: You could try https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many parser available you can google it. As oehman mention [CHCSVParser](http://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) is good to parse CSV files. Here is a blog which explains how to use it :-

http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/ios-csv-parser-writer/

This answer will help you too :-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537119/1865424

Answer (score 0):

I have used [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) to parse CSV files, and it does its job well (from my experience). Should be sample code included there as well.